Raspberry Pi Debug Probe: clock line driven low after programming target
As the subject line says, I am having an issue with the clock line of the debug probe being driven low after completion of programming my target chip.
Project setup overview: I am using the Raspberry Pi Debug Probe (currently firmware version 1.1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/debugprobe/releases/tag/picoprobe-cmsis-v1.1) to program a hex file onto an ATSAME51J19A. I'm utilizing OpenOCD (version 0.11.0-rc2) and running everything on a Debian system as part of a test fixture.
I am programming my target using the following command: `sudo openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/atsame5x.cfg -c "init" -c "program $1 verify reset exit where $1 is the argument containing the filepath to the hex file. The command programs my board successfully, however once the command finishes execution, the clock line continues to be driven low (which is causing problems when I am trying to run a board through a test script I have). Power cycling the debug probe (unplugging it and reconnecting it) after programming solves this issue, but minimally, just disconnecting the clock line after programming and before continuation of my test script allows everything to work as intended.
Things I have tried:
-Power cycle the target board (multiple times)
-Utilize other OpenOCD commands such as sudo openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/atsame5x.cfg -c "init" -c "cmsis-dap cmd 0x03" -c "exit" -d which is supposed to disconnect the DAP interface (0x03 specifies the DAP_DISCONNECT command per the CMSIS-DAP documentation as well as the OpenOCD source code) as well as the same command format but using the 0x0A option for target reset.
I believe that I have narrowed the issue down to it being related to the debug probe because I used another programmer (MPLab pickit4) and the clock line was left high at the conclusion of programming with that. Here are the oscilloscope captures for each programming method:
Debug Probe: https://imagetolink.com/ib/1I6flNrcbl
PicKit4: https://imagetolink.com/ib/G6PAsN0QAH
Has anyone else had this issue? Or know how to release the clock line or pull it high?

I'm sorry, but I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about the Open OCD software package, and not Raspberry Pi. FWIW, there is an 'Open OCD mailing list' that may be a good place to ask questions. Raspberry Pi Inc also maintains a GitHub repo devoted to OpenOCD... you may submit an "issue" there. Hope that helps!
